# Is there an out-of-universe explanation for why the Empire is prejudiced against non-humans?

Tags: star-wars

We know from canon and legends that the empire was prejudiced against non-human intelligent races, only allowing humans to serve in the imperial military. But is there an out of universe explanation for this in the original trilogy, such as the production of costumes being costly, or did Lucas have this in mind when he made the original trilogy and use it as a reason for dealing with issues such as cost?

Comment: Most actors in Hollywood are human?

Comment: @Buzz - Certainly a large majority

Comment: Because they're supposed to evoke the Nazis, therefore racism?

Comment: For a decent comparison of real world inspiration for many characters and events check out: [Star Wars and History](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-and-history).

Comment: @CearonO’Flynn - I don’t think so. One is explicitly in-universe (what was Palpatine thinking), and one is explicitly out-of-universe (what was Lucas thinking).